# Unknown C++ Vector and Function Errors

Tags: c++, function, stdvector

I am programming one of my very first C++ programs in Visual Studio Code, and want it to output all alphanumeric characters so that it is essentially a typing bot, but is made so that it outputs every single character a second, and would win almost instantly in an online typing game, such as nitrotype. Although, the accuracy would be very poor.

That being said, every time I run the code, I get a syntax error saying that there should be a semi-colon after the name of my vector and before the list of values in the vector.

For example, I `#include <vector>` and my vector inside of `main()` looks like this:

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> alphabet {" ", "a", "b", "c"}
```

I looked all throughout the code to make sure I wasn't missing any semi-colons, and made sure my `#include <vector>` statement was correct, but could not find anything.

My second issue thrown is that the `sleep()` function goes from `double` to `unsigned int`. I looked up how to use the sleep library with `#include <unistd.h>` and could not figure out why it threw an error.

My final error thrown is that there is no matching function for `typer(alphabet);` at the bottom. I believe I clearly defined the function `typer()` above `main()`, but keep on getting this error.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int x = 1;

std::string typer(letters) {
    while (x > 0) {
        std::cout << letters;
        sleep(0.166);
        return letters;
    }
}

int main() {

    std::vector<std::string> alphabet {" ", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", 
"g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u",
"v", "w", "x", "y", "z", ".", ";", ",", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7",
"8", "9", "(", ")" };

    typer(alphabet);
}
```

Comment: `std::string typer(letters) {` is missing the type for the function parameter. I'm not sure why that would give the error message you describe, but make sure to read error messages in order, since some mistakes might just get the compiler more and more confused.

Answer (score 1):

`#include <unistd.h>` is not a portable header. And its `sleep()` function does indeed take an `unsigned int`, not a `double`. If you are using C++11 or later, consider using the standard [`std::this_thread::sleep_for()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) in `<thread>` instead.

If you are using C++11 or later, the syntax you are using to initialize `alphabet` is fine. But, if you are using an older C++ version, that syntax not supported for `std::vector`. You will have to instead either `push_back()` each string individually, eg:

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> alphabet;
alphabet.reserve(41);
alphabet.push_(" ");
alphabet.push_back("a");
...
```

Or, you can use the `std::vector` constructor that accepts iterators, eg:

```cpp
std::string strs[] = {" ", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", 
"g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u",
"v", "w", "x", "y", "z", ".", ";", ",", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7",
"8", "9", "(", ")" };

std::vector<std::string> alphabet(strs, strs+41);
```

`std::string typer(letters)` is missing the data type for the `letters` parameter.
But even after fixing that problem, `typer()` still won't work the way you want, because `operator<<` doesn't know how to output a `vector`, you can't return a `vector` as a `string`, and the `while` loop is useless since you have a `return` on the 1st iteration. I suspect you wanted something more like this:

```cpp
std::string typer(const std::vector<std::string> &letters) {
    std::string result;
    for(const auto &str : letters) {
        std::cout << str;
        result += str;
        sleep(1000);
    }
    /* or: before C++11:
    for(size_t i = 0; i < letters.size(); ++i) {
        const std::string &str = letters[i];
        std::cout << str;
        result += str;
        sleep(1000);
    }
    */
    return result;
}
```

Comment: With chrono, you'll want to do `using namespce std::chrono_literals; std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);`

Comment: Regarding to your second paragraph: both the syntax of `std::vector<T> x = {....}` and `std::vector<T> x{....}` were added in C++11. In C++98 we had to push_back element by element.